# The virtual environment I am working on is not displaying in zsh

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am attempting to get the virtual environment I am working on to display in zsh. I believe the issue is the theme I am using, which is pygmalion. I would like to keep this theme but modify the theme so that my current virtual env will display on the left hand side in parenthesis, just like in bash. I have tried to fix the problem by adding this statement `export VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=` to my ~/.zshrc, but alas no luck. I am using oh-my-zsh as well. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the [pygmalion theme](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/pygmalion.zsh-theme) doesn't support virtualenv - compare this to say the [agnoster theme](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/agnoster.zsh-theme#L194), which does.

If you want to modify the code for the theme, the function from agnoster should be a good starting point.